# Does $|\mathfrak{Re}((8+i)^n+(4+7i)^n)| \to \infty$ when $n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Let $u_n=\mathfrak{Re}((8+i)^n+(4+7i)^n)$ ; thus $u_1=12,u_2=30,u_3=-36$ etc. Is it known whether $\lim_{n\to\infty}|u_n|=\infty$ ?

My thoughts : clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|u_n|}{r^n}=0$ when $r \gt \sqrt{65}$. Perhaps one can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|u_n|}{r^n}=\infty$ when $r\lt \sqrt{65}$ ?

Comment: Notice that $$u_n=65^{n/2} \cos \left(n \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\right)+65^{n/2} \cos \left(n
   \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)\right).$$ I think there might be some result needed on the irrationality of $\pi$ in order to prove/disprove that this diverges

Answer (score 3):

The factorizations
$$8+i=(3+2i)(2-i)
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
4+7i=(3+2i)(2+i),$$
show that
$$\operatorname{Re}((8+1)^n+(4+7i)^n)
=\operatorname{Re}\Big((3+2i)^n\big((2-i)^n+(2+i)^n\big)\Big),$$
where of course
$$(2-i)^n+(2+i)^n=2\cdot\operatorname{Re}\Big((2+i)^n\Big),$$
so the expression in your question simplifies to
$$\operatorname{Re}((8+i)^n+(4+7i)^n)
=2\cdot\operatorname{Re}\Big((2+i)^n\Big)
\cdot\operatorname{Re}\Big((3+2i)^n\Big).$$
Because $N(2+i)=5$ and $N(3+2i)=13$  this diverges.

Comment: Just wondering, how was this noticed?

Comment: I don’t quite understand why the right-hand side must diverge?

Comment: @Servaes amazing... wow haha